# how to combine two update statements

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two following update statements:

```
update tb1
set col1=1
where id in ('1', '2', '3')

update tb1
set col1=0
where id not in ('1', '2', '3')
```

Can I combine above two update statements into one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tb1 SET col1= CASE WHEN id in ('1', '2', '3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tb1 
SET col1 = CASE WHEN id in (1, 2, 3) 
                    THEN 1 
                WHEN id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
                    THEN 0
                ELSE
                    col1
           END ;
```